# Shift all the existing vowels in a Linked List at the end of the list in java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I was actually trying to implement a linked list which shifts all the existing vowels in the list at the end using java. Meaning, a list(linked) is given containing character in each node, I need to segregate its nodes in such a way that all nodes having a vowel are moved to the end of the linked list by maintaining there original order.

Output should be like:

```
original list: w->e->r->s->o->m->a->t
Output needed: w->r->s->m->t->a->e->o
```

I wanted to implement this in java. Please let me know what is the optimized way of doing it (like without using any extra lists). Any suggestions, help will be really appreciated.

Comment: If you want it in Java, why did you add C and C++ tags? I've removed those tags. If you want them back then please explain why.

Comment: @Mark, I was earlier trying to do in c, therefore added that by mistake.

Comment: Other than vowels last, must the letters keep their original order relative to each other?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: @Bohemian- Yes,letters have to keep their original order with respect to each other. And vowels have to maintain their original order at the end of the list irrespective to their positioning in the given list.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a LinkedList? An array of char entries would do, algorithm complexity could be O(n), you could move the chars with a helper array, while memory allocation is cheaper and performance better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
    LinkedList<Character> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList('w', 'e', 'r', 's', 'o', 'm', 'a', 't'));
    int n = list.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char c = list.get(i);
        if ("aeiuoAEIUO".indexOf(c) != -1) {
            list.remove(i);
            list.add(c);
            n--;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(list);
```

output

```
[w, r, s, m, t, e, o, a]
```

Comment: Thank you Evgeniy, Can you please let me know how will I maintain the original order of the vowels at the end of the list irrespective of there temporary positioning in the given list? And is there any possibility I could do this without creating any extra list( for optimization)

Comment: I like this because it does the shuffle in-place, almost like a `Queue`

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this, but there is most likely a more effective way of doing it.

```
private LinkedList reOrder(LinkedList<Character> chars) {
    LinkedList<Character> temporary = new LinkedList<Character>();
    for(Character a: chars) {
        if(a=='a' || a=='e' || a=='i' ||
           a=='y' || a=='u' || a=='o') {
            temporary.add(a);
        }
    }
    chars.removeAll(temporary);
    chars.addAll(temporary);
    return chars;
}
```

Comment: FYI This code will explode at `chars.remove(a);` with a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html). You can not modify a collection while using a foreach loop. Use an Iterator and `Iterator.remove()` instead.

Comment: This could probably be solved by changing chars to chars.copy() in the for-loop.

Comment: Thank you Lukas, can you please let me know if I could do this without creating any temporary or extra linked list? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I would define a custom `Comparator` object and then use `Collections.sort` to order the list. Here I define a comparator that will move all vowels to the end when used as an argument to sort:

```
class VowelSort implements Comparator<Character>
{

    private static boolean isVowel(Character c)
    {
        return "AEIOUaeiou".contains(c.toString());
    }

    public int compare(Character arg0, Character arg1)
    {
        final boolean vowel0 = isVowel(arg0), vowel1 = isVowel(arg1);

            //if neither of the characters are vowels, they are "equal" to the sorting algorithm
        if (!vowel0 && !vowel1) 
            {
            return 0;
        }

            //if they are both vowels, compare lexigraphically
        if (vowel0 && vowel1)
            {
            return arg0.compareTo(arg1);
        }

            //vowels are always "greater than" consonants
        if (vowel0 && !vowel1)
            {
            return 1;
        }

            //and obviously consonants are always "less than" vowels
        if (!vowel0 && vowel1)
            {
            return -1;
        }

        return 0; //this should never happen
    }
}
```

In main...

```
Collections.sort(chars,new VowelSort());
```

If you want consonants to be sorted as well just change

```
//if neither of the characters are vowels, they are "equal" to the sorting algorithm
if (!vowel0 && !vowel1)
{
        return 0;
}
```

to

```
//compare consonants lexigraphically
if (!vowel0 && !vowel1)
{
        return arg0.compareTo(arg1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you ValekHalfHeart This is really helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is really language agnostic, but here is one approach:

Iterate through the list once, as you are going, create a new list and remove every vowel you encounter from the original list and place them in the new list.

At the end simply append the new list on to the original list. As you removed the vowels as you were going then you would have moved all vowels to the end of the list.

Comment: Thank you so much! can you please show me how exactly we can perform the segregation?

Comment: I am not going to write this for you but the above answer should give you a good starting point to get going writing it in Java. If you have specific issues whilst doing so please do post those as well

Comment: The reason I have asked you to help me showing is because, I have already did that by creating two lists called consonants and vowels, and later merged them, I was actually curious can it be done in a more optimized way without using any extra list?

Answer (score 0):

Creating your own abstract data structure, you can store the content underneath as a char array.

```
char[] word = new char[] { 'f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r' };

char[] reordered = new char[word.length];

int vowel = word.length - 1;
int nonVowel = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    switch (word[i]) {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
        reordered[vowel] = word[i];
        vowel--;
        break;
    default:
        reordered[nonVowel] = word[i];
        nonVowel++;
        break;
    }
}
```

Now, the nonVowels are in the correct order, but the vowels are in inverse order. Depending on your use case, you could either invert the vowel suborder or define "get(position)", where you return:

```
if (position < nonVowel)
            return reordered[position];
        else
            return reordered[reordered.length - (position - vowel)];
```